# Div center aligned, with text left aligned, also left aligned with menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this text on top of a slider image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GvK5aow.png]

What I want, is to keep this text exactly as it is in the above screenshot on ALL browser sizes. The problem I am running into is as the browser size gets smaller the left aligned text is no longer aligned with the text in the menu as it is in the screenshot.

Here is the CSS for this text:

```
.line-middle{
    text-align: left;
    transform: translateX(-36%) translateY(-50%);
    width: 48%;
 }
```

Is there anything I can do to keep the text exactly as it is in the screenshot even if the browser size becomes smaller?

Comment: Please post the html and any other relevant scripts/styles that pertain to the test.

Comment: What if you made a separated div for the text and set it's position to absolute and it's height and width to 100%,then make another div in this div and set it's margin to auto

Comment: I may have a solution for you, but it really depends on your HTML markup. Could you post some?